# How do I write a given address to a register using inline assembly

Tags: c, arm, inline-assembly

I have the following statement:

```
asm volatile("ldr r0, =0x10000");
```

Instead of writing 0x10000 I want to write a parameter so it will look like this:

```
uint32_t addr = 0x20000;
asm volatile("ldr r0, =addr");
```

how can I manage to do it?

i am using ARM processor.

I want to do this:

```
At the end I want to do this:

asm volatile("ldr r0, =0x10000");
asm volatile("ldr r0, [r0]");
asm volatile("mov sp, r0");
```

same for pc

thanks.

Comment: That depends on your compiler. What compiler are you using?

Comment: BTW it doesn't make much sense to just write to a register in the middle of some C code, you are either going to mess up the code generated by the compiler (if you don't specify the clobber list) or just have it overwritten immediately after. If instead this is to prepare data for another assembly instruction, they should both be in the same assembly block, and generally `ldr` is redundant in extended asm if you specify your constraints/clobber lists correctly correctly. You should really provide some more context about what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

gcc is quite capable of generating those instructions so you can do:

```
void** p = 0x10000;
register void* sp asm("sp") = *p;
__asm__ __volatile__("" : : "r" (sp) : "memory");
```

Note it's dangerous to mess with `sp` so make sure you know what you are doing.

To load `pc` you will indeed need to use a `mov` such as:

```
void** p = 0x10000;
__asm__ __volatile__("mov pc, %0" : : "r" (*p) : "memory");
__builtin_unreachable();
```

Comment: hi, how I can do the same with pc?